# Gatsby Background Images & WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, gatsby

I am trying to set a background in Gatsby using [gatsby-background-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/?=background) plugin.

My query returns sourceUrl and alt-text just fine. However, when running gatsby develop it gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hero' of undefined". Doing some research I think I might have to use ChildImageSharp to specify fluid. However, I am not really sure if that is possible for an ACF field?

```
import React from "react"
import BackgroundImage from "gatsby-background-image"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <BackgroundImage
      className="masthead"
      fadeIn
      fluid={props.data.wordpress.pages.nodes.undersideACFgraphql.hero.sourceUrl}
    >
      <div className="black-overlay">
        <div className="content-box">
          <h1>This is where my h1 tag goes</h1>
          <h2>This is my sub head</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BackgroundImage>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query MyQuery {
  wordpress {
    pages {
      nodes {
        undersideACFgraphql {
          hero {
            sourceUrl
            altText
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Comment: You need to check it in localhost:8000/__graphql